# wifi p2p file transfer android connected device but not transfering

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

Hello iam stuck in problem since yesterday searched everything anywhere i create application which show device which arre connected to same router wifi , then iam able to connect both device using this exmple
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#creating-app
everything is okay both devices are connected but when transfer file serviceintent is not starting so thats why i cant transfer anything , there is not log error but happend nothing when i choose image to send

MainActivity Class

```
package com.b.wifip2p;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WpsInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pGroup;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener, WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener {
    Button button;
    private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
    private boolean retryChannel = false;
    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel = null;
    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pInfo info;
    BroadCast broadCast;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
    static List peers = new ArrayList();
    ListView lv;
    static Adapater myadapter;
    ArrayList<DeviceInfo_Bean>list=new ArrayList<>();
    private WifiP2pDevice device;
    String hostaddd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=findViewById(R.id.lv);
        myadapter=new Adapater(this,list);
        button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                connect();
            }
        });
        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                System.out.println("---sucess discover");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                System.out.println("---fail");
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 007);
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
                System.out.println("---ip"+ipAddress);


            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        broadCast = new BroadCast(mManager,  mChannel, MainActivity.this);
        registerReceiver(broadCast, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadCast);


    }
    private static WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void

        onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {

            List<WifiP2pDevice> refreshedPeers = (List<WifiP2pDevice>) peerList.getDeviceList();
            if (!refreshedPeers.equals(peers)) {
                peers.clear();
                peers.addAll(refreshedPeers);
                System.out.println("---ref"+refreshedPeers);


            }

            if (peers.size() == 0) {
                Log.d("-----deviceno", "No devices found");
                return;
            }

        }


    };




    @Override
    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
        for (WifiP2pDevice device : peers.getDeviceList())
        {
            list.clear();
           String address=device.deviceAddress;
           String  name=device.deviceName;
           System.out.println("---name"+name+address);
            list.add(new DeviceInfo_Bean(name,address));

       }
        myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("----", "Found some peers!!! " + peers.getDeviceList());
    }


    public void connect() {

        DeviceInfo_Bean device = list.get(0);

        WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
        config.deviceAddress = device.address;
        config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
        System.out.println("device in"+device.address);
        mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        // User has picked an image. Transfer it to group owner i.e peer using
        // FileTransferService.
        Uri uri = data.getData();
//        TextView statusText = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
//        statusText.setText("Sending: " + uri);
       // Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Intent----------- " + uri);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileTransferService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uri.toString());
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
                info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }



    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Context context;
        //private TextView statusText;

        /**
         * @param context
         *
         */
        public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            //this.statusText = (TextView) statusText;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8988);
                System.out.println("---socket");
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                ///Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");
                final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + context.getPackageName() + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + ".jpg");

                File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                if (!dirs.exists())
                    dirs.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();

                //Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
                OutputStream stream = client.getOutputStream();
                String s="---mymsg";
                stream.write(s.getBytes());
                Log.e("hello","context value "+context);

                InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
                copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
                serverSocket.close();
                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
              //  statusText.setText("File copied - " + result);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + result), "image/*");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           // statusText.setText("Opening a server socket");
        }

    }








    public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();
            long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
            Log.v("","Time taken to transfer all bytes is : "+endTime);

        } catch (IOException e) {
          //  Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(final WifiP2pInfo info) {
        System.out.println("---info");
            this.info=info;
       // view.setText("Group Owner IP - " + info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());


        InetAddress groupOwnerAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress;
        System.out.println("--g"+groupOwnerAddress);
        System.out.println("--info"+info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
            new FileServerAsyncTask(getApplication())
                    .execute();
        } else if (info.groupFormed) {
            // The other device acts as the client. In this case, we enable the
            // get file button.

        }

        // hide the connect button
       // mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void showDetails(WifiP2pDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
       // this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //    TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
      //  view.setText(device.deviceAddress);
        //view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        //view.setText(device.toString());
        System.out.println("---device"+device.deviceAddress);
    }

}'
```

Broadcast

```
package com.b.wifip2p;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;

import java.nio.channels.Channel;

/**
 * Created by BHM on 3/3/2018.
 */

public class BroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity activity;
    PeerListListener peerListListener=null;

    public BroadCast(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,
                                 MainActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.mManager = manager;
        this.mChannel = channel;
        this.activity = (MainActivity) activity;
    }



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("-----broadcast");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
             //   activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
               // activity.resetData();

            }
           // Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
            if (mManager != null) {
//                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, (PeerListListener) mChannel);
            }
      //      Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P peers changed");
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            if (mManager == null) {
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                // we are connected with the other device, request connection
                // info to find group owner IP


                mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, activity);
            } else {
                // It's a disconnect
               // activity.resetData();
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
//            DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
//                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
//            fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
//                    WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));
            intent.getParcelableExtra(
                  WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE);
        }
    }
    }
```

FileTransferService here intent is not coming

```
package com.b.wifip2p;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by BHM on 3/4/2018.
 */

class FileTransferService extends IntentService {

    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    public static final String ACTION_SEND_FILE = "com.example.android.wifidirect.SEND_FILE";
    public static final String EXTRAS_FILE_PATH = "file_url";
    public static final String EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS = "go_host";
    public static final String EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT = "go_port";


    public FileTransferService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("--intent");
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_FILE)) {
            String fileUri = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_FILE_PATH);
            String host = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS);
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT);

            try {
             //   Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Opening client socket - ");
                socket.bind(null);
                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

//                Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Client socket - " + socket.isConnected());
                OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
                ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileUri));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  //                  Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.toString());
                }
                    MainActivity.copyFile(is, stream);
      //          Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Client: Data written");
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // Log.e(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // Give up
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a slightly old question by now, but for those looking for answers:

I would recommend checking that you have the intent filters properly in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
It should look something like:

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SEND_FILE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```